# Deadlock on single table

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

We occasionally encounter the following deadlock:

Process 1: Multiple INSERTS into DeadlockedTable, inside a transaction

Process 2: Calling a table-valued function with multiple SELECTs on DeadlockedTable. Some of the SELECTS are within CTEs, some contain subselects on DeadlockedTable.

Deadlock:

```
Process 2 --> Request Mode S --> PageLock (DeadlockedTable) --> Owner Mode IX   --> Process 1
Process 2 <-- Owner Mode S   <-- PageLock (DeadlockedTable) <-- Request Mode IX <-- Process 1
```

The queries (only the ones using DeadlockedTable):

```
WITH T
AS (
SELECT ID1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY ENTRY_DATE DESC
        )
    ,*
FROM DeadlockedTable
WHERE ENTRY_ID = @ENTRY_ID
    AND ENTRY_TYPE = @ENTRY_TYPE
    AND ENTRY_DATE BETWEEN @FROM_DATE
        AND @TO_DATE
    AND SOURCE_ID IN (
        SELECT max(SOURCE_ID)
        FROM DeadlockedTable
        WHERE ENTRY_ID = @ENTRY_ID
            AND ENTRY_TYPE = @ENTRY_TYPE
            AND ENTRY_DATE BETWEEN @FROM_DATE
                    AND @TO_DATE
        GROUP BY ENTRY_DATE
        )
)
 INSERT INTO @dtTmpTable
 SELECT *
 FROM (
 SELECT min(ENTRY_DATE) AS ENTRY_DATE
    ,SRC_VALUE AS REF_DATE
FROM DeadlockedTable P
  WHERE P.ENTRY_ID = @ENTRY_ID
    AND ENTRY_TYPE = @ENTRY_TYPE
    AND ENTRY_DATE BETWEEN @FROM_DATE
        AND @TO_DATE
    AND SOURCE_ID IN (
        SELECT max(SOURCE_ID)
        FROM DeadlockedTable
        WHERE ENTRY_ID = @ENTRY_ID
            AND ENTRY_TYPE = @ENTRY_TYPE
            AND ENTRY_DATE BETWEEN @FROM_DATE
                AND @TO_DATE
        GROUP BY ENTRY_DATE
        )
GROUP BY SRC_VALUE
) #
 WHERE ENTRY_DATE NOT IN (
    SELECT rd.REFDATE
    FROM @dtTmpTable RD
    )

 UPDATE @dtTmpTable
 SET TotalValue = SRC_VALUE
 FROM @dtTmpTable
 INNER JOIN DeadlockedTable P ON P.ENTRY_ID = @ENTRY_ID
    AND ENTRY_TYPE = @ENTRY_TYPE
    AND ENTRY_DATE = refDate
 WHERE SOURCE_ID = (
    SELECT max(SOURCE_ID)
    FROM DeadlockedTable
    WHERE ENTRY_ID = @ENTRY_ID
        AND ENTRY_TYPE = @ENTRY_TYPE
        AND ENTRY_DATE = refDate
```

The indexes:

```
Index 1:  Non-Unique, Non-Clustered (SOURCE_ID)
Index 2:  Non-Unique, Non-Clustered (SOURCE_ID, ENTRY_ID, ENTRY_DATE, LOT)
```

I don't understand why process 2 would request multiple shared locks on DeadlockedTable. I would assume that a lock is only held for the duration of one SELECT and then released, is that wrong? What would be the right way to fix this?

Comment: What are your deadlock queries and table indexes? could you show it to us?

Comment: @D-Shih I can't post the entire function but I added the queries containing the table in question.

Comment: A simple solution is to just exclusively lock the whole table (`SELECT * FROM myTable WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK) WHERE 1=0`) at the beginning of the transaction. This will effectively serialize access to your table (and, obviously, kill performance if your transactions are not sufficiently short).

Comment: @Heinzi It is a long running transaction. Any chance I can fix this in the function? I still don't understand why multiple shared locks are necessary. Would it help to read all data required from DeadlockTable to a table variable and then only use the table variable in the selects?

Comment: @Stefan: You could try it, but I'm not sure if it would help. After all, it's the same SELECT as before, so it will probably be the same locking pattern. Usually the folks at dba.se are quite good at solving these things, but they need a reproducible example including a query plan to help.

Comment: We need to see the deadlock XDL, as well as the query plan (you can share via https://pastetheplan.com)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by following steps,

1. Use lock while inserting the records.[sp_getapplock (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

   ```
   EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = 'DeadlockedTable', @LockMode = 'Exclusive';
    --perform insertion work here 
    EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'DeadlockedTable';
   ```
2. Use with(nolock) while selecting the data from the DeadlockedTable

Comment: "Use `with(nolock)`" really bad idea, you are open to all sorts of race conditions and incorrect data